# What is wrong with my apple trees?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fruit-trees, apples

[image]

This is on some of my apple trees, can someone help me? What is going on and how do I treat it. Thanks

Comment: Is the bark peeling off of the tree?

Comment: Possibly related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4238/what-is-causing-the-bark-on-my-crabapple-to-crack-and-peel-off

Comment: Bark is not coming off at this point.

Comment: Hi! It looks like the system has created two user accounts for you, this one and the [original one](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/11240/mike) used to post the question. If you’d like to merge them (which will allow you to [edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept answers](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on your question), please see the [instructions](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Welcome to the site!

Comment: need a better description of what you see is the problem and a closeup

Comment: Does the fence (as shown in the image) keep large animals out or do e.g. deers have access?